# Unable to register service

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, prism, autofac

I'm trying to register a service using Prism autofac. However, I cannot seem to figure out a way to make this work. Everything I find on the internet is for older versions of prism and does not really show me how to use it now.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CashRegister>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<HamburgerMenu>("Index");
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Inventory>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Navigation>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Start>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<InventoryItemDetail>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<FolderCreate>();
    //containerRegistry.Register<SQLiteService>().As<ISQLiteService>();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<SQLiteService>().As<ISQLiteService>();
    builder.Build();
}
```

As you can see I tried it with the register container itself, but that did not really work since it did not recognize the `.As` method. Trying it with a new builder also gave me errors.

```
public class StartViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public StartViewModel(ISQLiteService sqliteService)
    {

    }
}
```

Here I try to use the registered type.

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

I found that you can use the build in builder using the `GetBuilder()` method but still getting an error.

[image: error autofac]

Comment: Can you provide some more context here. As your update shows yes you are able to directly access the ContainerBuilder through the `GetBuilder()` extension. I might assume that you're using SQLitePCLRaw in which case I would ask did you initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace tells us, that there is a `NullReferenceException` thrown *in* the constructor of `SQLiteService`. Without seeing your code I'd guess that there is some mandatory constructor parameter, but Autofac is passing `null`.

See [the Autofac documentation](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html) about how to pass parameters to your registered dependencies. Say we'll have to pass the name of the database file, we'd register `SQLiteService` as follows

```
containerRegistry.RegisterType<SQLiteService>()
    .As<ISQLiteService>()
    .WithParameter("databaseFile", "database.sqlite");
```